# Performing calculations on durations in iWork Numbers

Tags: iwork-numbers

I have a time sheet that I use to bill clients, with the following columns:

A: start time;
B: end time;
C: calculation of B - A, resulting in the duration of time worked;
D: Project name

On another sheet, I have a table with a list of projects and which client(s) should be billed for each.

Project 1 - Client A;
Project 2 - Client A;
Project 3 - Client B;
Project 4 - split between Clients A & B

Then in another table, I have a calculation using SUMIFS to tally the billable time for each client.

For Client A, it is:
SUM(SUMIF(D,"Project 1",C) , SUMIF(D,"Project 2",C) , (SUMIF(D,"Project 4",C)/2))

For Client B, it is:
SUM(SUMIF(D,"Project 3",C) , (SUMIF(D,"Project 4",C)/2))

In both cases, I get an error stating that SUM values must either be all durations or all numbers. I assume this is because when I divide the Project 4 durations in half, the result gets converted to a number rather than a duration.

Is there any way I can perform a calculation on a duration and have it remain a duration? Or is there a better way to draft my calculation?

*Disclosure: My spreadsheet is a lot more complex than described, and the SUMIF statements are actually SUMIFS that also account for the month in which the time should be billed. For the sake of clarity and brevity I omitted extraneous information. If anyone feels other info is relevant I can give more detail on the other aspects of the spreadsheet.*